# How to set radio buttons values based on dropdown selection?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, kendo-ui

I want to set radio buttons values based on drop-down selection,Lets assume i have three values in drop-down(A,B and C) , If A or B is selected i want to set radio button default value to Summary and if C is selected i want set value to Detailed. Also when A & B is selected i want to make it non-editable.. 
Please help this is first time i am using radios with AngularJS.

main.html

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="form-group col-md-6 fieldHeight">
        <label for="cycleName" class="col-md-6 required">Scope Type :</label>
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <select kendo-drop-down-list k-data-text-field="'text'"
                k-option-label="'Select'" k-data-value-field="'id'"
                k-data-source="assessmentTypeOptions" name="assessmentType"
                required ng-model="riskAssessmentDTO.scopeType" id="assessmentType"
                maxlength="256" ng-change="assessmentType()"></select>
                <p class="text-danger"
                    ng-show="addAssessment.assessmentType.$touched && addAssessment.assessmentType.$error.required">Assessment
                    Type is required</p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group col-md-6 fieldHeight">
        <label for="assessmentType" class="col-md-5 required">Assessment Type :</label>
        <label class="radio-inline"><input type="radio"
            name="summary" id="summary" ng-value="'summary'"
            ng-model="riskAssessmentDTO.erhFlag" ng-disabled="disableAssessmentType" >Summary </label>
        <label class="radio-inline"><input type="radio"
            name="detail" id="detail" ng-value="'N'"
            ng-model="riskAssessmentDTO.erhFlag" ng-disabled="disableAssessmentType">Detailed</label>
        <p class="text-danger"
            ng-show="addAssessment.includeERHFlag.$touched && addAssessment.includeERHFlag.$error.required">Assessment
            Name is required</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

main.js

```
$scope.assessmentType = function() {
                        $scope.riskAssessmentDTO.assessmentName = '';
                        $scope.riskAssessmentDTO.erhFlag = 'Y';

                        $scope.showRefineERH = false;
                        if ($scope.riskAssessmentDTO.scopeType === 'RA_GEO_LOCAT') {
                            $scope.disableAssessmentType = true;
                            $scope.riskAssessmentDTO.erhFlag = 'summary';
                        } else if ($scope.riskAssessmentDTO.scopeType === 'RA_LEGAL_ENTITY') {
                            $scope.disableAssessmentType = true;
                            $scope.riskAssessmentDTO.erhFlag = 'summary';
                        } else if ($scope.riskAssessmentDTO.scopeType === 'RA_BUS_UNIT') {
                            $scope.disableAssessmentType = false;
                            $scope.riskAssessmentDTO.erhFlag = 'detailed';
                        } 
                    };
```

Comment: "Also when A & B is selected i want to make it non-editable.." what you want to make non-editable?

Comment: radio buttons, user should not be able to make selection on radios, it should be disabled.

Comment: Is that your entire js file? Have you defined an angular module or controller?

Comment: yes that is working its piece of code that i am working on...

Comment: Okay, well you are using radio buttons in an odd way. A radio button should have a value of true or false, and you are assigning it a string value. You should have a different variable in your model for each of the radio buttons, then determine the value based on which radio button is selected, or has a value of true.

Answer (score 1):

Use ng-disabled in Radio buttons and use a scope variable as $scope.selectedIndex to set it as false or true

```
<input type="radio" ng-disabled="selectedInderx==0">
```

and set $scope.selectedIndex in the ng-change function in Select by passing $index from html

Comment: i changed some code in question ng-disabled is working based on dropdown values now i want to change radio button values.. How can i do that with above condtions ?

Comment: just set the value of Ng-model of radio buttons

Comment: i have edited my Js in question please have a look is it something i am implementing correctly.